# Responsive columns in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created one row with a single column(col-lg-12) and another row with two columns(col-lg-12).I noticed that in small devices,the first row does not properly align with the second row.

```
    <div class="container">  
     <!------------------------------------ first section-------------------------------------------------->
     <div class="row" id="firstSection">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
           <h2 class="heading2">Your home away from home</h2>
           <h4>Prima luce, cum quibus mons aliud consensu ab eo. Praeterea iter est quasdam res ex<br/>communi.Etiam habetis sem dicantur magna mollis euismod.</h4>
           <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae dolorem id in inventore, maiores consequuntur modi? Omnis dolore quam vel. Illo accusantium, porro laudantium saepe necessitatibus id ullam voluptate nihil!<br/></p> 
         </div>
    </div>
     <!------------------------------------ end of first section-------------------------------------------------->

     <!------------------------------------ second section--------------------------------------------------> 
    <div class="row" id="secondSection">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <article class="section1">                             
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
                    <h2>BUSINESS TRAVELLER</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi! and fre</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">READ MORE</button>              
                </article>      
            </div><!--  end of column --->

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <section class="section2">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
                    <h2>ACCOMPANYING A LOVED-ONE</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing       elit. Dolore eveniet distinctio non, dolor asperiores ducimus quidem. Tempore exercitationem, velit magnam beatae quia, similique, eaque aliquam provident inventore iste et sequi!</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">READ MORE</button>
                </section>
            </div><!--  end of column --->       
     </div><!-- row -->!>
      <!------------------------------------ end of second section------------------------------------------->
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

and below is the css code

```
   #firstSection{
   background-color:#ffffff;
   margin-left:12px;
   margin-right:12px;
   padding-top: 120px;
   margin-top:-80px;   
   }

   .section1{
   background: #ffffff;
   padding: 50px;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-left:px;
   }
   .section2{
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:30px;
    }
```

Comment: You have margin rules on your first row... but not on your second row.

Comment: actually the padding on the #firstSection should be 1px that it can align properly with the two boxes under.

Answer (score 1):

change your `<div>` declaration as follows

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12"> <!-- this will align the element in the same manner on small screen as it would have on larger screens -->
```

for identical alignment don't add any margin or padding to these divs

Comment: Works perfectly. The remaining problem is that the heading2(on the HTML code) of section2(col-lg-6) sticks out of the box when I fully scale the page down.

How do I make the heading never content never get out of the box at any time?

Comment: you applied the col-xs-6 class besides the col-lg-6 class right?

Comment: for the first row,using both col-lg-12 and col-xs-12 or just col-xs-12 works nice for the alignment of the boxes.
But still the heading 2 of the of the second column on the second row sticks out of the box when I scale the page down.

Comment: just put col-xs-12 it should be fine and just make a JSfiddle so that I can see the actual issue